# unable to set buefy modal width

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bulma, buefy

I am using vuejs with bulma and buefy. I am using buefy modal and trying to set the modal width using its 'width' property. I tried to specify it in the html as well as using javascript to open the modal.

```
this.$modal.open({
  parent: this,
  component: dummyComponent,
  width: 720
})
```

Can someone please help me out.

Answer (score 5):

You also need to set style="width: auto" in your component, then the width you set when opening the modal is taken into account.

Then the js part would stay

```
this.$modal.open({
  parent: this,
  component: dummyComponent,
  width: 720
})
```

and your component would be

```
<template>
  <div class="modal-card" style="width: auto">
   <!-- Content comes here... -->
  </div>
</template>
```

Examples in the [buefy documentation](https://buefy.github.io/documentation/modal/) include it as well but they don't explicitly state that you need it to make setting the width work.

Comment: thanks for the answer. but currently I am not working on this. need some time to verify and mark it as the correct answer. And also, I think this got fixed in the latest version. need to verify.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, for me it doesn't work.

```
this.$modal.open({
  parent: this,
  component: dummyComponent,
  width: 1200
})
```

It produces modal with 640px in width. If I set

```
<template>
  <div class="modal-card" style="width: auto">
    <!-- Content comes here... -->
  </div>
</template>
```

It produces even narrower modal, 460px. Not sure why.
My solution was:

```
<style lang="stylus" scoped>
  .modal-card
    width: auto
  @media (min-width: 1200px)
    .modal-card
      width: 1200px
</style>
```

Not a prettiest solution, but it works.
I also had to add z-index to .modal, as some parts of my html cover modal backdrop.